# MongoDB sort using a custom function

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have a collection that looks like:

```
{
  _id: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
  score: 10
  hours: 50
},
{
  _id: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab',
  score: 5
  hours: 55
},
{
  _id: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaac',
  score: 15
  hours: 60
}
```

I want to sort this list by a custom order, namely

```
value = (score - 1) / (T + 2) ^ G

score: score
T: current_hours - hours
G: some constant
```

How do I do this? I assume this is going to require writing a custom sorting function that compares the `score` and `hours` fields in addition to taking a `current_hours` as an input, performs that comparison and returns the sorted list. Note that `hours` and `current_hours` is simply the number of hours that have elapsed since some arbitrary starting point. So if I'm running this query 80 hours after the application started, `current_hours` takes the value of 80.

Creating an additional field `value` and keeping it constantly updated is probably too expensive for millions of documents.

I know that if this is possible, this is going to look something like

```
db.items.aggregate([
    { "$project" : {
            "_id" :  1,
            "score" : 1,
            "hours" : 1,
            "value" : { SOMETHING HERE, ALSO REQUIRES PASSING current_hours }
        }
    },
    { "$sort" : { "value" : 1 } } 
])
```

but I don't know what goes into `value`

Comment: Looks like you're nearly there already. Check out the [arithmetic expression operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#arithmetic-expression-operators) to help fill in `value`. Also, consider using $addFields rather than $project as a minor simplification

Comment: Oh also regarding potential persistence of `value`, it may be worth reconsidering that. Depending on the frequency and types of queries you issue, sorting on dynamically computed values may be rather expensive. The overhead marginal additional overhead for writes to maintain this value may be trivial compared to the benefits of [using an index to sort the query results](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes)

Comment: I don't really understand index creation since I'm fairly new to mongodb, but if I'm going to create this index for `value`, wouldn't it make more sense to just add a `value` field and periodically update it and simply sort on it?

Edit: also, thanks for the pointers

Comment: Indexes are only helpful for persisted values. We'd have to know more about your configuration, including about `current_hours` and its relationship to other values/documents) to say of there was a meaningful path forward there. For the question as written - I forgot to mention above that you may also need to use `$let` in the aggregation for that `current_hours` value (or just prepend another `$addFields` stage with it) if it is not something that is stored in the document already

Answer (score 0):

I think `value` will look something like this:

```
      "value": {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            score: "$score",
            t: {
              "$subtract": [
                80,
                "$hours"
              ]
            },
            g: 3
          },
          in: {
            "$divide": [
              {
                "$subtract": [
                  "$$score",
                  1
                ]
              },
              {
                "$pow": [
                  {
                    "$add": [
                      "$$t",
                      2
                    ]
                  },
                  "$$g"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

[Playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/93o1yQpEE6s)

Although it's verbose, it should be reasonably straightforward to follow. It uses the [arithmetic expression operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#arithmetic-expression-operators) to build the calculation that you are requesting. A few specific notes:

- We use `$let` here to set some `vars` for usage. This includes the "runtime" value for `current_hours` (`80` in the example per the description) and `3` as an example for `G`. We also "reuse" `score` here which is not strictly necessary, but done for consistency of the next point.
- `$` refers to fields in the document where `$$` refer to variables. That's why everything in the `vars` definition uses `$` and everything for the actual calculation in `in` uses `$$`. The reference to `score` inside of `in` could have been done via just the field name (`$`), but I personally prefer the consistency of this approach.

Comment: My pleasure. You should be able to accept it as the correct answer if it indeed answered the question